# Thread.Sleep - how to use it in a proper way?

Tags: c#, .net

`System.Threading.thread.Sleep(1000);` pauses a whole program for 1 second, but when this second is over it does everything what could be done for this period. For example:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("A");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.Writeline("B");
```

It will wait two seconds and write

> A
>   B

How to use the pause properly?

Comment: Not able to reproduce this. Is this the whole code? I'm asking because there's a typo in your example: `Writeline` should be `WriteLine`.

Comment: In general, the proper way to use `Thread.Sleep` is not to use it at all. What are you trying to do? It's likely that what you're trying to do can be done without resorting to putting the thread to sleep.

Comment: I'm trying to run a separate endless thread in a programm, but there must be a break for 1 second between it's iterations. This "code" may be a bad exxample of what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep()` behaves just like you would think; it just pauses the current thread for approximately the given number of milliseconds.

The problem here is that the standard output stream does not necessarily flush to the console (or wherever it is pointed at) to on each call to Write. Instead, it may buffer some content so as to write it out in larger chunks for efficiency. Try calling `Console.Out.Flush()`; after each WriteLine() and you should see the results you expect.

Comment: It's not about a console applications only. WinForms behave in the same way

Comment: Is there any method to pause the application of any type  or a single thread?

Comment: @user3493623 Thread.Sleep() will pause any type of application. If you want something to happen periodically, consider using a Timer

Answer (score 4):

If you want something to happen once per second, then create a timer. For example:

```
private System.Threading.Timer _timer;

void main()
{
    _timer = new Timer(TimerTick, null, 1000, 1000);
    // do other stuff in your main thread
}

void TimerTick(object state)
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

There are several different types of timers. If you're writing a console program, then I would suggest using [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In a Windows Forms application, either `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer`. See [Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdzx8wx8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.